# On smooth structure of quotient manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, solution-verification, smooth-manifolds

> Let $M$ be a smooth manifold of dimension $m>1$. Let $\sim$ be an equivalence relation on $M$ such that the graph of this relation makes a smooth, closed and $(2m-1)$ dimensional submanifold of $M \times M$.
> Show that if $\pi : M \to M/\sim$ be an open map then $M/\sim$ has a smooth structure such that with respect to it $\pi$ would be a smooth immersion.

My attempt : Since the graph of $\sim$ is closed in $M \times M$, and $\pi : M \to M/\sim$ is an open map, $M/\sim$ is Hausdorff. $M/\sim$ is second countable as well since open elements in $M/\sim$ (i.e. all elements of each equivalence class), form an open set in $M$ and vice versa (since $\pi^{-1}(U) \subset M$ is open in $M$), Therefore the image of a basis of $M$ in $M/\sim$ is a basis (topological basis).

We construct smooth structure of $M/\sim$ from structure of $M$: Let $U\subset M/\sim$ is open then $\pi^{-1}(U) \subset M$ is open in $M$.
We know that $f : N \to M \times M$ ($N$ is the set of equivalent pairs) is smooth submanifold of $M \times M$ with $2m-1$ as its dimension. So by rank theorem, for each $x \in M$, $f^{-1}( {\{ x}\} \times M)$ is a smooth submanifold of $N$ but its second component is the set of elements equivalent to $x$. And its dimension is $2m-2$, so $M/\sim$ is a manifold with a smooth structure.

Am I rigorously correct?

Comment: It's not clear how you use rank theorem?

Comment: Is this an exercise (if yes, can you state the source?)

Comment: @ArcticChar no this is from the exam I had yesterday and the teacher teaches from Lee's smooth manifolds book. My attempt is my answer I wrote whether correct or not